# Make Current/Active Page Number a Link (WP_LINK_PAGES)

Tags: php, functions, links, wp-link-pages, nextpage

With the default wp_link_pages the current/active page number is not a link. I would like to find a code/hack which turns the current/active page into a link to the top of the page.

I am already using a custom code for wp_link_pages which can be found below:

```
<?php
wp_link_pages(array(
    'before' => '<p class="pagelinks">' . __(''),
    'after' => '</p>',
    'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', # activate parameter overloading
    'nextpagelink' => __('Next'),
    'previouspagelink' => __('Previous'),
    'pagelink' => '%',
    'echo' => 1 )
);
```

In my functions:

```
// Custom Next/Previous Page
add_filter('wp_link_pages_args', 'wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add');
/**
 * Add prev and next links to a numbered link list
 */
function wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add($args)
{
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    if (!$args['next_or_number'] == 'next_and_number')
        return $args; # exit early

    $args['next_or_number'] = 'number'; # keep numbering for the main part
    if (!$more)
        return $args; # exit early

    if($page-1) # there is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page($page-1)
            . $args['link_before']. $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
        ;

    if ($page<$numpages) # there is a next page
        $args['after'] = _wp_link_page($page+1)
            . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
            . $args['after']
        ;

    return $args;
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like there are proper hooks to modify the output as per your requirements. But you could write a function similar to `wp_link_pages()` and call that in your theme. The following function would do your trick.

```
function custom_link_pages($args = '') {
        $defaults = array(
                'before' => '<p>' . __('Pages:'), 'after' => '</p>',
                'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '',
                'next_or_number' => 'number', 'nextpagelink' => __('Next page'),
                'previouspagelink' => __('Previous page'), 'pagelink' => '%',
                'echo' => 1
        );

        $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
        $r = apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_args', $r );
        extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

        global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow;
        $output = '';
        if ( $multipage ) {
                if ( 'number' == $next_or_number ) {
                        $output .= $before;
                        for ( $i = 1; $i < ($numpages+1); $i = $i + 1 ) {
                                $j = str_replace('%',$i,$pagelink);
                                $output .= ' ';
                                if ( ($i != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) ) {
                                        $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
                                } elseif ( $i == $page ) {
                                    $output .= '<a href="#">';
                                }
                                $output .= $link_before . $j . $link_after;
                                if ( ($i != $page) || ( $i == $page ) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) )
                                        $output .= '</a>';
                        }
                        $output .= $after;
                } else {
                        if ( $more ) {
                                $output .= $before;
                                $i = $page - 1;
                                if ( $i && $more ) {
                                        $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
                                        $output .= $link_before. $previouspagelink . $link_after . '</a>';
                                }
                                $i = $page + 1;
                                if ( $i <= $numpages && $more ) {
                                        $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
                                        $output .= $link_before. $nextpagelink . $link_after . '</a>';
                                }
                                $output .= $after;
                        }
                }
        }

        if ( $echo )
                echo $output;

        return $output;
}
```

You can use this function in the same way as `wp_link_pages()`.

**EDIT**

To include both page numbers and next/previous links you should even add this filter to your functions.php.

```
// Custom Next/Previous Page
add_filter('wp_link_pages_args', 'wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add');
/**
 * Add prev and next links to a numbered link list
 */
function wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add($args)
{
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    if (!$args['next_or_number'] == 'next_and_number')
        return $args; # exit early

    $args['next_or_number'] = 'number'; # keep numbering for the main part
    if (!$more)
        return $args; # exit early

    if($page-1) # there is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page($page-1)
        . $args['link_before']. $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
    ;

    if ($page<$numpages) # there is a next page
        $args['after'] = _wp_link_page($page+1)
        . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
        . $args['after']
    ;

    return $args;
}
```

And to call the pagination you would put the following in you template or loop.

```
custom_link_pages(array(
    'before' => '<p class="pagelinks">' . __(''),
    'after' => '</p>',
    'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', # activate parameter overloading
    'nextpagelink' => __('Next'),
    'previouspagelink' => __('Previous'),
    'pagelink' => '%',
    'echo' => 1 )
);
```

Comment: Am I supposed to add this in addition to what I have in my functions right now or replace what I have with this?  Also, do I call it as I have been calling wp_link_pages in my original example?

Comment: You can replace your code with the code I have provided and instead of calling `wp_link_pages()` you can call `custom_link_pages()`. It also accepts the same arguments as `wp_link_pages()`.

Comment: In my code in the original the code makes it so that both page numbers and next/previous links are displayed (usually WordPress).  I'm trying to now combine these two codes but I'm not advanced enough at PHP to do so, would you be able to help me out with that?
(And thanks!)

Comment: Ok you just need to use your `add_filter('wp_link_pages_args', 'wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add')` code thats it, and pass the same arguments to `custom_link_pages` as you had passed to `wp_link_pages`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I honestly have no idea what that means or how to do it.  :-S

Comment: Ok I have edited the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JoshuaAbenazer This works awesomely. Is there a way that you can extend it so you can add a custom class to the rest of the anchor tags?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way I'm using now, is to use 'link_before' and 'link_after' as part of the wp_link_pages args. You can then wrap each number, including the active one, in a tag, then style appropriately.